# Get str before HS code: digit (exclude HS code: some digit)

Tags: python, c#

txt = '''293 PACKAGE(S)x000D PRINTED HEAD ITEM: KA02033-E844 A5 :INVOICE: FIT-2401-01 HS CODE: 84732:100 KNITTED FABRIC H.S CODE: 6006.2:2.00 INV#: TSTEX0124-009 (TC-240021:) WOVEN TWILL CAP HS.CODE: 6505.00:.90 KNITTED FABRIC HS 600410 FABRIC: P57101 (T989, 100% POLYESTER, WIDT:H 152CM) HS CODE : 54075200_x000D_ (*)EMA:IL:IMPORT-SHA@ZHL.CN USCI:913101141:32276439L (**)USCI:

Container DRYU9124108: 13 PACKAGE(S), AUTOMATIC TOOTH TURNING MACHINESD-CYJ500-1000 HS CODE:84597010;
'''

I would like to take get string before HS code: digit* (exclude HS code: some digit)
ex: ['293 PACKAGE(S)x000D PRINTED HEAD ITEM: KA02033-E844 A5 :INVOICE: FIT-2401-01','KNITTED FABRIC','WOVEN TWILL CAP','KNITTED FABRIC','KNITTED FABRIC','FABRIC: P57101 (T989, 100% POLYESTER, WIDT:H 152CM)','Container DRYU9124108: 13 PACKAGE(S), AUTOMATIC TOOTH TURNING MACHINESD-CYJ500-1000']

Try Python:
import re

txt = '''293 PACKAGE(S)x000D PRINTED HEAD ITEM: KA02033-E844 A5 :INVOICE: FIT-2401-01 HS CODE: 84732:100 KNITTED FABRIC H.S CODE: 6006.2:2.00 INV#: TSTEX0124-009 (TC-240021:) WOVEN TWILL CAP HS.CODE: 6505.00:.90 KNITTED FABRIC HS 600410 FABRIC: P57101 (T989, 100% POLYESTER, WIDT:H 152CM) HS CODE : 54075200_x000D_ (*)EMA:IL:IMPORT-SHA@ZHL.CN USCI:913101141:32276439L (**)USCI:

Container DRYU9124108: 13 PACKAGE(S), AUTOMATIC TOOTH TURNING MACHINESD-CYJ500-1000 HS CODE:84597010; '''

x = re.findall(r'(.+?)(?:(?=hs code:\s*\d*)|(?=hs.code:\s*\d*))', txt, re.S|re.IGNORECASE)

print(x)

Result: ['293 PACKAGE(S)x000D\nPRINTED HEAD ITEM: KA02033-E844 A5 :INVOICE: FIT-2401-01 ', 'HS CODE: 84732:100 KNITTED FABRIC H.S CODE: 6006.2:2.00 INV#: TSTEX0124-009 (TC-240021:) WOVEN TWILL CAP ', 'HS.CODE: 6505.00:.90 KNITTED FABRIC HS 600410 FABRIC: P57101 (T989, 100% POLYESTER, WIDT:H 152CM) HS CODE : 54075200_x000D_\n(*)EMA:IL:IMPORT-SHA@ZHL.CN USCI:913101141:32276439L (**)USCI: \nContainer DRYU9124108: 13 PACKAGE(S), AUTOMATIC TOOTH TURNING MACHINESD-CYJ500-1000 ']

result includes "HS code: digits".

Comment: Sometimes it says "H.S. CODE".  Sometimes it says "HS.CODE".  Sometimes it says HS CODE".  Those are all different.  Perhaps you should just look for "CODE:".  This may be another case where a regexp is not the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more generalized regex would be to start with a non-space character and use a non-greedy wildcard to match until a variation of `H.S. CODE : non-spaces` (where dots, `CODE`, colon and spaces are all optional) is encountered:

```
re.findall(r'(\S.*?)\s+H\.?S\b\.?(?:\s*CODE)?\s*:?\s*\S+', txt)
```

Demo on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/uKNisV/1

Demo on ideone: https://ideone.com/UcWvrl

Note that there is no reasonable way to extract `WOVEN TWILL CAP` from `INV#: TSTEX0124-009 (TC-240021:) WOVEN TWILL CAP` unless `INV#: non-spaces non-spaces` is special-cased. If you're willing to special-case it then you can do:

```
(?:INV#:\s*\S+\s+\S+\s+)?(\S.*?)\s+H\.?S\b\.?(?:\s*CODE)?\s*:?\s*\S+
```

Demo on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/uKNisV/2

Demo on ideone: https://ideone.com/GkubmJ

Comment: Thank @blhsing. It worked perfectly. You save me a lot of time !!!